# Disable menu in report_Aeroo on form

Tags: python, report, odoo

I make an Excel Report using **Report_Aeroo** but I have Little bit problem over here I make a **wizard** and from that I am generating a Excel Report so I don't want Menu of it on my Form view of model which I passed in Report.So what can I Do ??
like we have functionality in **rml's** like **"Menu =false"** anything same in **Report Aeroo???**

Answer (score 0):

I believe the entry is multi=True or alternatively I think you will find that just going in to the report and using the remove print button will do it.